# Column-wise subset of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset, between

I need some help with subset/filter of data.frame. Below is the code for my random dataset.

```
A <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
B <- c(3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
C <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4)
Fakey <- data.frame(A, B, C)
Filter_Fakey <- subset(Fakey, (Fakey>1 & Fakey<4))
```

That last line of coode results in the following:

```
> Filter_Fakey
       A  B  C
5      2  4  3
6      2  4  3
7      2  4  3
8      2  4  3
9      3  1  2
10     3  1  2
11     3  1  2
12     3  1  2
NA    NA NA NA
NA.1  NA NA NA
NA.2  NA NA NA
NA.3  NA NA NA
NA.4  NA NA NA
NA.5  NA NA NA
NA.6  NA NA NA
NA.7  NA NA NA
NA.8  NA NA NA
NA.9  NA NA NA
NA.10 NA NA NA
NA.11 NA NA NA
NA.12 NA NA NA
NA.13 NA NA NA
NA.14 NA NA NA
NA.15 NA NA NA
```

But What I really want is this,

```
> Filter_Fakey
       A  B  C
5      2  3  3
6      2  3  3
7      2  3  3
8      2  3  3
9      3  2  2
10     3  2  2
11     3  2  2
12     3  2  2
NA    NA NA NA
NA.1  NA NA NA
NA.2  NA NA NA
NA.3  NA NA NA
NA.4  NA NA NA
NA.5  NA NA NA
NA.6  NA NA NA
NA.7  NA NA NA
NA.8  NA NA NA
NA.9  NA NA NA
NA.10 NA NA NA
NA.11 NA NA NA
NA.12 NA NA NA
NA.13 NA NA NA
NA.14 NA NA NA
NA.15 NA NA NA
```

I've tried `subset(), subset(with a negation condition), filter{dplyr}`, and the different bracket notations `('['` and `'[[')`. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: What exactly is happening between the original dataframe and the desired output? It appears that the rows in the output are not in the original data so you aren't really just _subsetting_...

Comment: My code is basically filtering data for Column A. Column B & C there is no subsetting taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lapply` to loop through columns of the data frame, and set values out of conditions to be `NA` if that is what you are after. Use `order(is.na(...))` to arrange `NA` values to the last positions:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(Fakey, function(col) {
                             col[col <= 1 | col >= 4] <- NA; col[order(is.na(col))]
                         }))

    A  B  C
1   2  3  3
2   2  3  3
3   2  3  3
4   2  3  3
5   3  2  2
6   3  2  2
7   3  2  2
8   3  2  2
9  NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA
11 NA NA NA
12 NA NA NA
13 NA NA NA
14 NA NA NA
15 NA NA NA
16 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you @Psidom, but I have some doubts. Lets say I remove the following part      col[order(is.na(col))] from the code. it ends up returning NA all over. Why is that happening? Sorry, I'm just trying to break it down and see how it works for my learning.

Comment: If you remove all the part, the function returns nothing, so you get all `NA`. If you want to break it down, replace `col[order(is.na(col))]` with `col`.

Comment: And if you don't need all the `NA` s, which I don't see any reason to keep but you might have your own purpose, you can simply do `do.call(cbind, lapply(Fakey, function(col) {col[col > 1 & col < 4]}))`.

Comment: You are right, I won't be keeping NA's. I plan on replacing >1 & <4 with <UL & >LL from another data set.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `length<-` to pad NA at the end after subsetting each of the columns using the logical condition.

```
data.frame(lapply(Fakey, function(x) `length<-`(x[x > 1 & x <4], nrow(Fakey))))
#    A  B  C
#1   2  3  3
#2   2  3  3
#3   2  3  3
#4   2  3  3
#5   3  2  2
#6   3  2  2
#7   3  2  2
#8   3  2  2
#9  NA NA NA
#10 NA NA NA
#11 NA NA NA
#12 NA NA NA
#13 NA NA NA
#14 NA NA NA
#15 NA NA NA
#16 NA NA NA
```